# JPA -Table column references as foreign key to two different tables

Tags: mysql, jpa, foreign-keys, one-to-many, many-to-one

Hello dear developers,

my current situation: I'm using JPA 2.1 and in one table I have a column which references in a foreign key relationship to two different tables.

How can this be described in JPA?

```
Table Book 
  taxRateId (manyToOne) (GermanTax/AustrianTax)
  countryType

Table GermanTax
  taxRateId (oneToMany Books)

Table AustrianTax
  taxRateId (oneToMany Books)


CONSTRAINT germanTax FOREIGN KEY (tax_rate_id) REFERENCES german_tax (id)

CONSTRAINT austrianTax FOREIGN KEY (tax_rate_id) REFERENCES austrian_tax (id),
```

Comment: In both GermanTax & AustrianTax, is the taxRateId column Primary Key?

Comment: Another question: could you specify the relationships between tables?

Comment: Hi, yes the taxRateId column is a primary key. I described also in parenthesis the relationships

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this mapping approach:

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Tax {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "taxRateId")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk-sequence")
    //@SequenceGenerator(name = "pk-sequence", sequenceName = "ID_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    protected Long taxRateId = -1;

    public long getTaxRateId() {
        return taxRateId;
    } 

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private double taxRate;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String countryName; // countryType ?

    // getters and setters for 'taxRate' and `countryName`
}
```

Next, we define two concrete *Tax* entities such as follows:

```
@Entity
public class AustrianTax extends Tax {
    // nothing special here, the type differentiates enough
}

@Entity
public class GermanTax extends Tax {
    // nothing special here, see above --^
}
```

Then, we map `Book` in a generic way to `Tax`

```
/*
 * As you brought up the question
 */
@Entity
public class Book {
    // fields & annotations for ID attribute and generation strategy, similar to above

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Tax> countryRates;

    // getters and setters, add and remove for 'countryRates' 
}
```

**However**, it would be more precise - and compliant to a data model in *3NF* - to define it as follows:

```
/*
 * One book can refer to 1 or more rates (Austrian/German) AND 
 * One rate can be applied to 1 or more books -> @ManyToMany
 */
@Entity
public class Book {
    // fields & annotations for ID attribute and generation strategy, similar to above

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Tax> countryRates;

    // getters and setters, add and remove for 'countryRates' 
}
```

General assumption / rationale for the latter case (`@ManyToMany`):

A certain book (the very same book) is sold in different countries which raise different tax rates. Therefore, my advice would be to change the database schema (Table structures) if you can. This would/will result in a *n:m* table to map the relationship

> `|Book| 0..* <--> 0..* |Tax|`

correctly (in a semantical sense). Footnote: I hope you are still in an early stage of development.

The only thing left is the attribute `countryType` which I can't associate to be an attribute of the type `Book` assuming that a book is not modified for *Austrian* dialects and therefore printed with different content (speaking as a German here ;-) ). For most D-A-CH books, however, this wouldn't be a regular case.

Hope this helps.